# For loop: Print the car name with the highest result. If they are equal, take the first one

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am starting with simple C++ codes and I am stuck with an easy task...

I have to show the maximum speed value and the fastest car, after comparing two cars.

To do that, I designed a function **maxSpeedCar,** that calculates the value "maximum speed". Then I store that value within variable **fastestCar**.

If the **fastestCar** is greater than **result** (which is initialized at 0), then **result** = **fastestCar**. So, everytime a car has a greater maximum speed I store the value within **result** and I store the name of the car as a **bestCar**

However, if the maximum speed of the "car 0" is the same as the maximum speed of the "car 1", I want to print the "car's 0 name", thats why I am storing cars[i-1] as **bestCar**. And here it is the problem. My code is not taking "car's 0 name" as the best car when the maximum speed is the same. Instead of that it keeps taking "car's 1 name" as the best car...

Finally, I also designed the function writeCar, that takes two parameters and prints them. It prints the maximum speed (result) and the name of the car (bestCar).

Do you know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot,

```
    result = 0;
    for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
        fastestCar = maxSpeedCar(cars[i]);
        if (fastestCar == result) {
            bestCar = cars[i-1];
        } else {
            if (fastestCar > result) {
                result = fastestCar;
                 bestCar = cars[i];
            }
        }
    }

// Show results
    
    writeCar(bestCar, result);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: add rest of you code, this does not make sense.

Comment: It seems like you're looking for a [*stable sort*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort). With the right criteria the wanted element can be made to be the first in the container.

Comment: Show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As little I could understand from this code, you just need the else statements. Remove the whole first if block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could help. Try running this and let me know if it doesn't work.
You just update if only if you get a car with more speed. If you get a car with equal speed or lower that the current maximum `result`, you don't update and this way your `bestCar` still stores the first ever maximum found and discards all those cars which just matches its speed.

```
    result = 0;
    for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
        fastestCar = maxSpeedCar(cars[i]);
        if (fastestCar > result) {
            result = fastestCar;
            bestCar = cars[i];
        }
    }

// Show results
    
    writeCar(bestCar, result);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer risingStark. What you say makes all the sense to me but I am still getting the second car's name. So, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Maybe I do have a problem with some of the functions because the for loop seems correct to me.

It should only take the first car maximum speed and name since we are not doing anything when the second car has the same maximum speed.

Thanks anyway!